# Coldfusion, linear interpolation formula / function?

Tags: math, coldfusion

Is there any function / formula for linear interpolation in coldfusion? Had a look on cflib.org no luck.

Comment: Ahh just did this..  y = y1 + [(y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)]·(x - x1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(y = y1 + [(y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)]·(x - x1)

So..

```
<cfset res =  y = y1 + ((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)) * (x - x1)>

<cfdump var="#res#">
```